# Запись HTML объектов в JS массив

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Есть такой HTML

```html
<tr id="dayWrap">
  <td><?php echo $price_6; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $price_5; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $price_4; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $price_3; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $price_2; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $price_1; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Нужно значения из каждого td загрузить в массив, чтобы в дальнейшем обращаться к нему выгружая данные при определенном действии. Спасибо!

Comment: `var prices = $('#dayWrap td');`, и затем обращаться по индексатору `prices[0]...`

Comment: @guitarhero в метках нету `JQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как вариант так можно попробовать

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('#dayWrap');

let values = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++ ) {
 values.push( parent.children[i].innerHTML );
}

console.dir( values );
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="dayWrap">
    <td>1 - one</td>
    <td>2 - two</td>
    <td>3 - three</td>
    <td>4 - four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

прокути их в цикле и получешь массив

```js
var arr = []
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {

  arr = td[i].innerHTML;
  console.log(arr)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="dayWrap">
    <td>
      <?php echo $price_6; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $price_5; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $price_4; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $price_3; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $price_2; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $price_1; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чисто в учебных целях, еще можно сделать так :

```js
let td = document.querySelectorAll('#dayWrap td');

var result = Array.from(td).map((e) => {
  return e.innerHTML;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="dayWrap">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Парни, может кто-то подскажет. Делаю как вот в последнем примере и получаю вот что http://prntscr.com/lhyyea   сам код который вставил http://prntscr.com/lhyz14  Тоже самое, только свой id вставляю. а строка выглядит в дом-дереве вот так: http://prntscr.com/lhyzr8   В чем проблема? У вас все выходит..у меня нет

Comment: судя по всему у вас ИД число, вот почитайте : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html