# Собрать все элементы <Tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сразу извиняюсь за дубликат. Проблема та в том что как в дубликате не выходит. Хотя все идеально делаю..

Беру от сюда [Запись HTML объектов в JS массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731137/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-html-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-js-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Делаю как вот в одном из ответов в примере и получаю вот что [image: prntscr.com/lhyyea] сам код который вставил

[image: ![prntscr.com/lhyz14][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfah2.png)

Тоже самое, только свой id вставляю. а строка выглядит в дом-дереве вот так: [image: ![prntscr.com/lhyzr8]

В чем проблема? У всех все выходит..у меня нет

Comment: "как вот в одном из ответов" - мне надо угадать, на какой ответ Вы намекаете? Задайте нормально вопрос, с кодом и разметкой. А то минус поставлю ).

Comment: Не надо править понапрасну вопрос... Убери картинки, добавь код

Comment: id элемента обязан начинаться с буквы.

Comment: Исправил, в первом тот что считается правильным ответом

Answer (score 0):

Вам написали про `id`, но если сильно надо:

```
let parent = document.querySelector('[id="' + e + '"]');
```

Поскольку у Вас уже и так используется `onclick`, можно проще:

```
<tr onclick="sss(this)">

function sss(parent) {
  ...
}
```

P.S. Мне непонятно, как сюда относится заголовок вопроса.

---

> Вроде ж все просто.

Что Вам сказать? *Вы же программист.* Почему Вы объясняетесь картинками? Предположим, я хочу Вам помочь (почему?) и сделать работающий пример с разметкой и кодом. Я должен сам напечатать весь js и html с первого до последнего слова. Но я не хочу Вам помочь *до такой степени*. Если бы у Вас в вопросе был работающий пример с объяснением - "вот что я хочу получить, а вот - что получаю", это был бы другой разговор.

Comment: Ну я ж элементы с Tr  хочу записать в массив, точнее их значения. Вроде ж все просто.   Вот что у меня выходит когда делаю по вашему примеру. Он сразу все вытаскивает. А по коду должен отдельности.  http://prntscr.com/li08kc

Answer (score 0):

Не?

```js
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  var td_arr = [];
  $('#add_arr td').each(function(){
    var td_text = $(this).text();
    td_arr.push(td_text);
  });
  console.info(td_arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="add_arr">
  <tr>
    <td>Авдей</td>
    <td>Богдан</td>
    <td>Вадим</td>
    <td>Гавриил</td>
    <td>Даниил</td>
    <td>Евгений</td>
    <td>Ждан</td>
    <td>Зиновий</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="button">Собрать в массив</button>
```